# Using a different external port for mariadb on Centos7

Tags: mysql, port, mariadb, centos7

I'm trying to allow remote access to a single mysql database on a different port.

I have added the user and granted all privileges from % to the specific database.

I've added the external bind address and commented out skip-networking from /etc/my.cnf

I've flushed privileges on mysql (technicall mariadb)

And I've setup the port forwarding in firewalld using

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=53306:proto=tcp:toport=3306

I've reloaded firewalld.

I'm testing using dbforge studio but I'm still not able to connect remotely.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that SELinux is enabled:

- you certainly need to configure port labelling on port 53306 (see http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-use-selinux-port-labelling/).
- you also need to check if a particular SELinux boolean has to be set (see http://www.certdepot.net/selinux-diagnose-policy-violations/).

Regards.